# SQL Server 2005 32 bit -Error: The OLE DB provider "OLEDB.1" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider ran out of memory

Tags: mysql, memory-management, sql-server-2005, dynamic-memory-allocation

Since recently I have noticed some of my jobs are failing with above error. When I google it found this below article - https://www.johnsansom.com/sql-server-memory-configuration-determining-memtoleave-settings/

```
WITH VAS_Summary AS
(
    SELECT Size = VAS_Dump.Size,
    Reserved = SUM(CASE(CONVERT(INT, VAS_Dump.Base) ^ 0) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
    Free = SUM(CASE(CONVERT(INT, VAS_Dump.Base) ^ 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY, SUM(region_size_in_bytes)) [Size],
            region_allocation_base_address [Base]
            FROM sys.dm_os_virtual_address_dump
        WHERE region_allocation_base_address <> 0
        GROUP BY region_allocation_base_address
        UNION
        SELECT
            CONVERT(VARBINARY, region_size_in_bytes) [Size],
            region_allocation_base_address [Base]
        FROM sys.dm_os_virtual_address_dump
        WHERE region_allocation_base_address = 0x0 ) AS VAS_Dump
        GROUP BY Size
    )
SELECT
    SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, Size) * Free) / 1024 AS [Total avail mem, KB],
    CAST(MAX(Size) AS BIGINT) / 1024 AS [Max free size, KB]
FROM VAS_Summary WHERE FREE <> 0
```

The I got the below results from mySQL

Total avail mem, KB ||  Max free size, KB
69448               || 3264

This article says about VAS memory What i am not sure is this to do with VAS memory? If so how do I clear it or increase it? I am not a pro level at this mearly first time ever saw this and going to Server memory, Can some one help me please. If you someone can tell step by step method would be good for me to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out Thanks to below

http://www.wonderwaremidwest.com/wp-content/uploads/TN1042.pdf